# Unifying the width of two elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have two elements : one div and one image. I want the width of div tag to be equal to the width of image.

```
<div class="preff">
<img src="http://stackoverflow.com/"></img>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want to set the width of the image to be the width of the div?

Comment: OK..................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(".preff").width($("img").width());`

Also as previously stated by Pete, I would suggest giving each element an id to use.

Answer (score 1):

First, would suggest giving your elements IDs or classes. You can get the width of elements in jquery using:

```
elementOne = $('#elementOne').width();
```

Then change the CCS width of other elements using your `elementOne` variable or result of calculations that use it. Syntax for changing Jquery CSS:

```
$('#elementTwo').css("width",elementOne);
```

(I can't remember if you need to include 'px' in this last statement, you may need to concat that onto `elementOne`)